# Using JSON data with identical keys (in D3)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I found a JSON file with containing historical events on this website [here](http://www.vizgr.org/historical-events/search.php?format=json&begin_date=-3000000&end_date=20151231&lang=en):

The structure of the file is as follows:

```
{ result:
    {
        count: "37859",
        event: {},
        event: {},
        ...
        event: {}
    }
}
```

As you can see, every objects containing data about a particular event is stored within its own object but all of them have the same key, "event". Because of this the result of the d3.json() method is only the last "event" object. How can I get an array of all of these "event" objects?

Sorry if I'm using the word "object" in a wrong way, they are represented as objects in the browser console and I don't know how else to describe them as in english.

Comment: This question has no answer and therefore should be closed. It has nothing to do with D3: in JavaScript, object keys must be **unique**. Again, JavaScript objects cannot have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

The file they're providing to you is not valid JSON so I can't see any way of using `d3.json()` and getting it to work.

I think you have two options here:

- Speak to the provider and get them to format the file properly.
- Load the file as text instead of JSON, use `string.replace` to reformat the structure to be an array of events, rather than a collection of fields called event on that object.

Something like this:

```
{
    result:
    {
        count: "37859",
        events: [
            { ...event1... },
            { ...event2... },
            { ...event3... }
        ]
    }
}
```

An easier option might be to replace each occurrence of the string `"event"` with a unique version like `"event-1"`, `"event-2"`.